# CakePHP 3 Plugin reference JS in a Template file

Tags: javascript, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.x, cakedc

I have my register.ctp Template file in my Users plugin that I want to reference a js file that is also within my plugin

```
vendor/cakedc/users/webroot/js/password-compare.js
```

How do I reference this js file in my Template file?

I've tried

```
<?= $this->Html->script("password-compare"); ?>
<?= $this->Html->script("Users.password-compare"); ?>
<?= $this->Html->script("/Users/webroot/js/password-compare"); ?>
```

and then

```
<?= $this->fetch('script') ?>
```

But nothing has worked so far...  any hints?

Comment: Are You installed CakeDC/Users by Composer?

Comment: Yes, installed via composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up just adding the following code, works fine but not as elegant as I might of liked...

```
<script src="<?= $this->request->webroot ?>/cake_d_c/users/js/password-compare.js"></script>
```

Comment: In CakePHP 4.x, access to $this->request->webroot is protected (it was public in 3.x). I believe this is an equivalent: `$this->request->getAttributes()['webroot']`

Answer (score 0):

Using "plugins" word in Cake is ambiguous, because plugins can be localized in `plugins/` directory or can installed (by Composer) to `vendor/` directory.

Correct argument in `script();` method in HtmlHelper is `Users.password-compare`, but this is for plugins in `plugins/` directory.

If You using plugin like as vendor and You has `loadPlugin('CakeDC/Users')` in bootstrap.php file and there is correct path in file "vendor/cakephp-plugins.php" all thing schould be works fine.

Comment: That's not quite correct, the HTML helper (or any other functionality that uses plugins) doesn't care where the plugin is located in the filesystem, it doesn't even have to be in either `plugins` or `vendor`, when loading plugins you can specify an arbitrary path as the source, all the helper needs is the correct name/alias that was used to load the plugin via `Plugin::load()`.

Comment: Yes, ndm is more correct on that.  The plugin is loading correctly as expected.  However, I want to have some JS files with jQuery loading for a specific Template (View by the old CakePHP 2 nomenclature) and I want to keep all the files together in the plugin.  Using script('Users.password-compare') outputs <script src="/myapp/js/Users.password-compare.js"> as the path.

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp 3.4 and over this work for me:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \App\View\AppView $this
**/
$this->Html->script('password-compare.js', ['block' => true]);
?>
```

Without ['block' => true] don't show in html the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

A small detail that is not immediately obvious, for someone unfamiliar with the short echo tag.

This:

```
<?= $this->Html->script("Users.password-compare"); ?>
```

is the same as:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script("Users.password-compare"); ?>
```

You need to echo the assets. This was my issue for my scripts not loading, as I was migrating from 2.10, where echo was not needed.

Please see: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/plugins.html#linking-to-assets-in-plugins